# parsing xml with Python minidom

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to parse elements from .xml file with Python minidom library, but it doesn't seem to work. It's returning "IndexError list out of range". Perhaps I'm using incorrect method/library for the job. Please suggest how to do this. Thanks

```
from xml.dom import minidom
doc = minidom.parse('/path/to/file/runParameters.xml')
docs = doc.getElementsByTagName('RunParameters')
for el in docs:
    cloud = el.getElementsByTagName("EnableCloud")
    print(cloud[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
```

Here is what the structure of the file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RunParameters xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <EnableCloud>false</EnableCloud>
  <RunParametersVersion>MiSeq</RunParametersVersion>
  <CopyManifests>true</CopyManifests>
  <FlowcellRFIDTag>
    <SerialNumber>000000000-AG01C</SerialNumber>
    <PartNumber>17772</PartNumber>
    <ExpirationDate>2016-04-10T00:00:00</ExpirationDate>
  </FlowcellRFIDTag>
</RunParameters>
```

Comment: Your code+xml works for me. Is the xml file name correct?

Comment: Yes, it's spelled correctly and returns:`print(cloud[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I added an answer with my test code. Please give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RunParameters xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <EnableCloud>false</EnableCloud>
  <RunParametersVersion>MiSeq</RunParametersVersion>
  <CopyManifests>true</CopyManifests>
  <FlowcellRFIDTag>
    <SerialNumber>000000000-AG01C</SerialNumber>
    <PartNumber>17772</PartNumber>
    <ExpirationDate>2016-04-10T00:00:00</ExpirationDate>
  </FlowcellRFIDTag>
</RunParameters>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(root.find('.//EnableCloud').text)
```

output

```
false
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. Please try it on your system:

```
xx = '''
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RunParameters xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <EnableCloud>false</EnableCloud>
  <RunParametersVersion>MiSeq</RunParametersVersion>
  <CopyManifests>true</CopyManifests>
  <FlowcellRFIDTag>
    <SerialNumber>000000000-AG01C</SerialNumber>
    <PartNumber>17772</PartNumber>
    <ExpirationDate>2016-04-10T00:00:00</ExpirationDate>
  </FlowcellRFIDTag>
</RunParameters>
'''.strip()

with open('test2.xml','w') as f:
   f.write(xx)
   
from xml.dom import minidom
doc = minidom.parse('test2.xml')
docs = doc.getElementsByTagName('RunParameters')
for el in docs:
    cloud = el.getElementsByTagName("EnableCloud")
    print(cloud[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
```

Output

```
false
```